# Punctuation character following a '\left(...\right)^3' group?

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I'm attempting to reproduce an existing display math.

[image: existing display math]

```
\begin{equation*}P=50,210,000\left(\frac{t}{D}\right)^3\!,\end{equation*}
```

This produces:

[image: typeset display math]

I would like to shove the trailing comma back under superscript.

I have tried various combinations of spacing commands to no avail.

Thanks in advance for advice, including any "Don't do that" suggestions.

Comment: how about ```50.21\times 10^6 \left( \frac{t} {D}\right)^3``` ? You can still use the comma in the end if you really want to use it.

Comment: @fromthebeeland I don't see how that affects the trailing comma.  (Although I do agree that it's useful to change the leading coefficient.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speaking for myself, I think the final comma should be placed somewhere to the right of the `3` power term, as the comma is *not* part of the formula itself. Of course, just how far to the right of the formula it should be placed is subject to debate. See below for a specific suggestion.

I would like to recommend that you make several changes.

- Load the `mleftright` package and use its `\mleft` and `\mright` macros instead of `\left` and `\right` to reduce the amount of whitespace around the large parentheses.
- Reduce the horizontal space between the parenthetic term and the power term by replacing `^3` with `^{\!\!3}`.
- Optionally, load the `siunitx` package with the option `group-separator={,}` and replace `50,210,000` with `\num{50210000}`. This will get the correct spacing around the thousands-separators. If you don't want to use the `\num` macro in this way, you really should encase both commas in curly braces; doing so changes their math status from math-punct to math-ord, implying that TeX won't insert extra space after them.
- Use but a single `\!` directive before the final comma. That way, the overall "picture" of the formula is nice and compact, while still providing a visual clue that the final comma is *not* part of the formula itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'equation*' environment
\usepackage{mleftright} % for '\mleft' and '\mright' macros
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P
&= 50,210,000\left(\frac{t}{D}\right)^3, \quad\texttt{before} \\[2ex]
&= \num{50210000}\mleft(\frac{t}{D}\mright)^{\!\!3}\!, \qquad\texttt{after}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Logically you're right, but sometimes fitting an equation and any trailing punctuation onto one line trumps that (especially in a 2-column layout).  I reckon the majority of `\!`'s I've ever used were in 2 equations in one paper for that reason (full-width equations weren't handled well by the journal especially with plentiful figures - the downside of a small theoretical section in an experimental paper). Much of the was tucking the superscripts in like your 2nd suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisH - I fully agree with the proposition that if you absolutely, positively have to economize on horizontal whitespace (say, because of a two-column layout requirement and a long-ish formula, you'll sometimes do things you otherwise would never consider doing. :-) One such measure is to reduce the default values of `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip`, and `\thickmuskip`, possibly to as little as `0mu`...

Answer (score 4):

- If you’re writing a long number with commas as place separators, you should write those commas using `{,}` instead of `,`. The former gives “ordinary” spacing so you won't have the extra space between the commas and the following digits.
- My instinct for the comma is don't do that, but if you really want to do it, you can do something like the following:

  ```
  \left. % ❷
  \left(
  \frac{t}{D}
  \right)
  \! % ❸
  \rlap{,} % ❶
  \! % ❸
  \right. % ❷
  ^{3}
  ```

  We make the comma stick out to the right ❶ by enclosing it in `\rlap` (overlap to the right). However, this will also cause the superscript to be attached to the comma instead of to the parentheses so we’ll put a pair of invisible delimiters ❷ around the parentheses.¹ Finally, everything is a bit spaced out more than we'd like so I threw in some negative thin skips ❸ to tighten the whole formula.

---

1. Normally we see `\left.` and `\right.` used to create unmatched big delimiters for things like multi-line equations or constructions like a case. This is the first time I’ve ever had cause to match them up.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the default output that the comma is after the superscript 3 is suitable since the comma is used for the entire equation. But if you want the output as you like, see the following three ways:

```
\begin{equation*}P=50,210,000\left(\frac{t}{D}\right)^3\!\!\!,\end{equation*}%just to add 2 more \!
\begin{equation*}P=50,210,000\left(\frac{t}{D}\right)^3\hspace{-0.23cm},\end{equation*}%the value can be reset as you like
\begin{equation*}P=50,210,000\left(\frac{t}{D}\right)^3\kern-0.25cm,\end{equation*}%the value can be reset as you like
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

And if you use them frequently, you can define a command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\equationcomma}{\!\!\!,}
\newcommand{\equationcomma}{\hspace{-0.23cm}}
\newcommand{\equationcomma}{\kern-0.25cm}
```